# Highlight if 2 different values in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

would anyone be able to help?
I am trying to write VBA to highlight if the cell has 2 different values. It seems to highlight all including the same name appear twice. Thanks for any help!

```
Sub CountTwoOrMoreDifferent()
Dim myRange As Long
myRange = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2:A" & myRange).Select
For Each AnimalName In Selection
    AnimalNameMoreThan2 = AnimalName.Value
    If InStr(AnimalNameMoreThan2, "Cat") + _
    InStr(AnimalNameMoreThan2, "Dog") + _
    InStr(AnimalNameMoreThan2, "Cow") _
    + InStr(AnimalNameMoreThan2, "Chicken") + _
    InStr(AnimalNameMoreThan2, "Snake") + _
    InStr(AnimalNameMoreThan2, "Tums") + _
    InStr(AnimalNameMoreThan2, "Drop") > 1 Then
    AnimalName.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    Next AnimalName
End Sub
```

Data in column A

Sample Data

[image]

Comment: Suggest you break into two steps: 1) the logic, 2) turning that into VBA. It looks as though the logic should probably be: Split input on ; value into n elements. Highlight the cell if any of the n elements are the same. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I believe the question is how to check for duplicates from a collection? Do you copy all entries one by one to another temporary collection while checking the presence? Or do you sort a collection and see if any entry is equal to the previous one? Once you have created such a user-defined function (UDF), you can use it as input for a conditional formatting rule.

Comment: @zsalya. Thanks for the question. What I am looking for is... if a cell has Drop;Drop, do not highlight this, but if the cell 1 or more value not the same, for example, Tums;Drop Tums is not the same as Drop, so highlight this. So if a cell not have same value separates by semicolon, highlight that in red.

Comment: @Dominique I didn't think through about duplicate check, you made a good point. I was hoping, the conditional formatting would help, but, I didn't get it to work either. By any chance you'd have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

It is split into two parts

- a sub - which does the check per cell.
- a function that checks if there is a duplicate within an array.
  It returns true in case there is at least one dup.

```vb
Public Sub highlightDuplicateValues()

'get Range to check
Dim lastRow As Long, rgToCheck As Range
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rgToCheck = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow)        'no need to select!
End With

Dim c As Range, arrValuesInCell As Variant
Dim i As Long

For Each c In rgToCheck.Cells
    'get an array of values/animals in cell
    arrValuesInCell = Split(c.Value, ";")
    
    'now check for each value if it has a dup - if yes color red and exit check
    For i = LBound(arrValuesInCell) To UBound(arrValuesInCell)
        If hasDupInArray(arrValuesInCell, i) = True Then
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub

Private Function hasDupInArray(arrValues As Variant, checkI As Long) As Boolean

'only values after the checkI-value are checked.
'Assumption: previous values have been checked beforehand

Dim varValueToCheck As Variant
varValueToCheck = arrValues(checkI)

Dim i As Long
For i = checkI + 1 To UBound(arrValues)
    If arrValues(i) = varValueToCheck Then
        hasDupInArray = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ike, I will use this and may make adjustment as I have larger set of data. Thanks again for sharing or helping!

Comment: if you put the part within the for each loop into a single function returning true if duplicates have been found (instead of coloring) then you can use the function for conditonal formatting.

Comment: As you're new on SO: please don't forget to accept (and maybe upvote) my answer if it helped you to solve your problem. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you @ike. I see your point now. I think your codes might work. THanks again!